# Kotlin exceptions not all shown in crashlytics

Tags: android, kotlin, proguard

I joined an ongoing project, this project uses Proguard.
I already had some problems because of Proguard and I solved it as line numbers and class names wasn't showing correctly in crashlytics

My problem now, that I see the correct line and class name but the exception is just `Kotlin.b`

[image: Fatal Exception Kotlin.b]

What is missing to show the correct exception, and does Proguard has something with this or not

Here is my Proguard file, I am open for suggestions in general if there is something wrong with my Proguard file as it is my first time to use it

```
-optimizationpasses 1
-dontpreverify
-verbose

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class android.content.Context
-keep class com.gauravbhola.ripplepulsebackground.RipplePulseLayout$RippleView { *; }

#-keep,includedescriptorclasses public class androidx.** { *; }
#-keep,includedescriptorclasses public class android.support.** { *; }
#-keep,includedescriptorclasses public class com.google.** { *; }
-keep,includedescriptorclasses public class io.fabric.sdk.** { *; }

# Keep AppMeasurement
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public static com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement getInstance (android.content.Context);
}
-dontwarn com.google.**
-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn androidx.**
-dontwarn io.fabric.sdk.**

-optimizations !class/unboxing/enum


-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** v(...);
    public static *** w(...);
    public static *** i(...);
}

# this will fix a force close in ReadingActivity
-keep public class org.jsoup.** {
    public *;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

#skip running ProGuard on Crashlytics
-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.crashlytics.**

# The I2P Java API bundled inside the I2P Android client library contains
# references to javax.naming classes that Android doesn't have. But those
# classes are never used on Android, and it is safe to ignore the warnings.
-dontwarn net.i2p.crypto.CertUtil
-dontwarn org.apache.http.conn.ssl.DefaultHostnameVerifier

-dontwarn org.apache.http.HttpHost

# Needed for okhttp
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn javax.annotation.Nullable
-dontwarn javax.annotation.ParametersAreNonnullByDefault

# there were 11 unresolved references to classes or interfaces
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
# -dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-dontwarn org.conscrypt.**
# A resource is loaded with a relative path so the package of this class must be preserved.
# -keepnames class okhttp3.internal.publicsuffix.PublicSuffixDatabase

# Preserve annotations, line numbers, and source file names
-keepattributes *Annotation*,SourceFile,LineNumberTable

-keepattributes InnerClasses,EnclosingMethod
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that with using Proguard, you have to add `-keep' for your custom exceptions
I wondered if this is the problem and it is not handled, so I added

```
-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception
```

and now Kotlin exceptions are shown in the Crashlytics